# Compiz features stopped working when an external monitor is attached

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, compiz, gnome-classic

Running 12.04 on a thinkpad T520 with nVidia NVIDIA Quadro NVS 4200M graphics. Just updated to the lasted nvidia 310 driver. Everything works great. However, as soon as I attached an external monitor using nvidia twinview, compiz features such as scale (moves all the active windows in one page) stopped working, as well as alt-tab to list all opened programs. Any ideas how i can fix this? never had this problem with 11.04. I can post my xorg.conf if that's of use to you. Thanks much!

edit 1: I am using gnome3 classic

edit 2: alt-tab works -- compiz application switcher (by default for gnome3 / unity) will crash gnome-classic, by changing to "static application switcher" in compiz seemed to solve the problem, but the scale still does not work when an external monitor is attached.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type:

```
compiz --replace
```

this should hopefully fix it.

If not, type:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

This will install a settings manager for compiz and related features.

Comment: I have compiz manager installed, disable and re-enable scale did not work, compiz --replace didn't work either, instead it removed my windows decorator.

Comment: In the past `compiz --replace` hasn't worked well for me because if I close the terminal window that I ran the command from, compiz closes.  Try `compiz --replace &` instead.  Whether or not that's the solution to your problem is another matter altogether...